# Delphi ADODB Create dbf table

Tags: delphi, ado, dbf

I have to create dbf file in my Delphi application.

For this case I use ADODB.

Connection string:

```
const
  ConnStringDBF =
  'Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;Dbq=%s;';
  //'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=dBASE III;OLE DB Services=-1;Data Source=%s;';
  //'Driver={Microsoft Visual Foxpro Driver};SourceType=DBF;SourceDB=%s;';
  //Driver='Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=%s;';
```

And procedure (which doesn work):

```
procedure InsertRecordInDBF(file_name: string; DbfRecord: TDbfRecord);
var
  ADOConnDBF  : TADOConnection;
  ADOCommand : TADOCommand;
begin
  ADOConnDBF := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
  ADOConnDBF.ConnectionString := Format(ConnStringDBF, [data_dir]);
  ADOCommand := TADOCommand.Create(nil);
  ADOCommand.Connection := ADOConnDBF;
  ADOCommand.CommandText := 'Create Table ' + file_name + ' ('
                        + 'NUMBER CHAR(11)'
                        + ')'
                        ;
  ADOCommand.Execute;
end;
```

The error is:

raised exception class EOleException with message '[Microsoft][Драйвер ODBC dBase] Ошибка синтаксиса при определении поля'.

Which means: syntax error in translation from Russian.

But this CommandText works perfectly:

```
  ADOCommand.CommandText := 'Create Table ' + file_name + ' ('
                        + 'NUMBER_ CHAR(11)'
                        + ')'
                        ;
```

The difference in the name of the field (**Number_** instead of **Number**)

How can I create table with field Number?

Maybe I need different connection string?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that I found solution for this problem. The right syntax is:

```
  ADOCommand.CommandText := 'Create Table ' + file_name + ' ('
                        + '[NUMBER] CHAR(11)'
                        + ')'
                        ;
```

I added [] to the name of the field

Answer (score 0):

Use VFPOLEDB provider with the following connection string:

```
Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source=%s;Password="";Collating Sequence=MACHINE
```

In this case your CREATE TABLE clause will work fine.